# Space between @Html.Textbox and glyphicon

Tags: css, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I am sure I am just overlooking the obvious, but I am having a little trouble with a "fairly simple" problem. I'm just trying to place a glyphicon next to a textbox (in ASP .NET MVC razor). However, there is a space between them, I cannot get rid of. It looks like on the below screenshot.

Razor code:

```
<div class="input-group col-md-4">
    @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Search" })
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Have anybody had the same problem? How did you resolve it? Thanks a lot in advance.

N.

[image: Example]

Comment: Cannot duplicate this at all. You must have some css causing it (perhaps a `max-width` on the input)

Comment: @ user3559349 identified the solution to my particular problem ~ thanks ~ I've posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
<div class="input-group">
 @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Search" })
 <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
</div>
```

when you use **btn btn-default** it's contain **padding** and also alignment. For this reason you loss your style. so flow the example and use **onClick** Event for submit this value.

**Update:**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" style="font-weight: normal;">Date</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "form-control" })
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Ashiquzzaman but still, it does not looks good. The textbox is longer now and the space between them bigger.

Comment: @Nearshore i update answer with my existing and working code.

Comment: Thank you again! Yeah, but it is TextBoxFor. For my search, I just need a textbox. I tried with a different bootstrap layout - same issue. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Nearshore. it's my working code and i use it about 20 project.

Comment: This problem drives me crazy! :-( Thank you, for your support!

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem and the comment by @user3559349 was the resolution.

I added a css script override to my view as follows

```
<style>
input, select, textarea {
    max-width: none;
}
```

My re-rendered control now looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and ended up using Bootstrap's form-inline class in the form tag.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("*actionName*", "*controller*", *routeValues*, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
{
<div class="input-group col-md-4">
    @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Search" })
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
}
```